# Oracle query that can filter paired data

Tags: oracle

I need some help with an Oracle query that can skip 'pairs' and only pick non paired data. Example:

```
Id      cost   hour type
123     $1.00  1    Input 
123     $1.00  1    Output 

234     $2.00  4    Input
345     $5.00  4    Output

236     $3.00  5    Input
236     $3.00  3    Output
```

In this example, the first two lines are a 'pair', since thir first 3 fields match; 3rd and 4th, and 5th and 6th lines are not a 'pair', since their first three fields do not match.

Comment: But... but...  what if the second row was IDENTICAL to the first, they both show INPUT and there is no OUTPUT for id = 123, cost = $1.00, hour = 1? Are they still a pair? Or do you need to give a better / more accurate explanation of what a "pair" is? And another question: What if you had TWO rows identical to the first one you gave (with Input), and only one with Output? Is there "a pair" and then you still need to select ONE COPY ONLY of the "Input" row?

Comment: the pair is 'input' and 'output' with the first 3 attributes matching ( first 2 records in the example) - the next two sets do not match - Yes I need the ones that do not have either 'input' or 'output' to be reported along with the unmatched 'pairs' - thanks again for clarifying. Hope I have explained it right

Answer (score 0):

You may use window function and Partition by

```
select id, cost, hour, type
  from (
  select id, cost, hour, type,
         count(*) over(partition by id, cost, hour) as cn
  from mytable) t
where cn=1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , let me try

Comment: @user3096366 this wont give you the first pair, after I read Mathguys comment I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: right - I want the first pair to be skipped and only 2 & 3rd (in the example) reported. Thanks Vercelli

Comment: @user3096366 Glad to hear it. Feel free to mark it as answer.

Comment: @Vercelli - I don't think you understood what OP meant. He confirmed my suspicion. You can see how that works in the Answer I posted. OP will confirm if that's what he meant all along.

Comment: @Vercelli - I am learning (slowly!) how to do all the analytics in one pass over the base table. Until recently I would have separated the table in two, for Inputs and Outputs, would have done analytics on each and an aggregate, and then would have joined... a lot of unnecessary effort. What I am saying is, it can be learned, and the practice here on SO is nice!

Answer (score 0):

I changed column name "hour" to "hours" and "type" to "type_" (it is not good to use reserved Oracle words as object names, including column names). I assumed the cost is given as a number, not with the $ sign shown. (If it's a string, that's a bad idea to begin with.)

```
with
     input_data ( id, cost, hours, type_ ) as (
       select 123, 1.00, 1, 'Input'  from dual union all
       select 123, 1.00, 1, 'Output' from dual union all
       select 234, 2.00, 4, 'Input'  from dual union all
       select 345, 5.00, 4, 'Output' from dual union all
       select 236, 3.00, 5, 'Input'  from dual union all
       select 236, 3.00, 3, 'Output' from dual
     ),
     prep ( id, cost, hours, type_, rn, pairs ) as (
       select id, cost, hours, type_,
              row_number() over (partition by id, cost, hours, type_ order by null),
              least ( count(case when type_ = 'Input'  then 1 end) 
                                        over (partition by id, cost, hours),
                      count(case when type_ = 'Output' then 1 end) 
                                        over (partition by id, cost, hours)
                    )
       from input_data
     )
select id, cost, hours, type_
from   prep
where  rn > pairs
;
```

`row_number()` counts the rows for fixed id, cost, hours and type_ (I don't care in what order, I just need them "enumerated") and `pairs` counts how many pairs there are. In the final select, I just keep rows where the row_number is greater than `pairs` - that does exactly what you need.

```
        ID       COST      HOURS TYPE_
---------- ---------- ---------- ------
       234          2          4 Input
       236          3          3 Output
       236          3          5 Input
       345          5          4 Output

4 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lag()` **analytic** function should suffice.

```
    select * from stackovf svf where id not in (select id from (select svf.*, 
    (case when lag(id) over (partition by id,cost,hour order by 1)=id 
    and lag(cost) over (partition by id,cost,hour order by 1)=cost 
    and lag(hour) over (partition by id,cost,hour order by 1)=hour then 1
    else 0 end )as match_found 
    from stackovf svf)  
    where  match_found=1)
```